# Convergence of the power series $\sum \left(\frac{n^n}{n!} x^n \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Find the convergence radius of the serie

$$\sum \frac{n^n}{n!}x^n $$

and analyze the absolute convergence and/or uniform.

**What I've done**:

- It is easy to show that the radius of convergence of this series is $R=\frac{1}{e}$. Then, the series convergence absolutely and uniformly on the interval$\; \left(-\frac{1}{e}, \frac{1}{e} \right)$
- Analyzing the convergence at $x=\frac{1}{e}$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945066/divergence-of-the-serie-sum-fracnnn-frac1en/945219#945219/)), the serie does not comverges.
- Analyzing the convergence at $x=\frac{-1}{e},$ the Dirichlet test says that the serie converges, if I didnt do anything wrong, using the same factorial aproximation we've seen before

I have some questions about what I've done and the difference between absolute and uniform convergence.

1. Since the uniform convergence talks about series of functions, I think that does not makes sence to "analyze the uniform convergence" st the interval extremes. Is that correct?But it does makes sence to talk about uniform convergence at $[-\frac{1}{e}, \frac{1}{e})$! I am confuse about this part.
2. I think the final answer should be that the series converges absolutely and uniformly at the interval of convergence and converges at the interval of convergence and for $x=\frac{1}{e},$ if I didnt do anything wrong.

I hope my questions are clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to be a _little_ careful about applying the Dirichlet test here - you need very explicit bounds on the magnitude of $\dfrac{n^n}{n!e^n}$, and bounds that are good enough to show that the terms are strictly decreasing in magnitude - just saying that they're of 'size $\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$' isn't quite good enough.  The bounds mentioned in your other question should be enough to prove the strict inequality, but you do need to do that before you can use Dirichlet.

Comment: (As an example of what can go wrong, imagine the sequence $a_{2n} =\dfrac1{\sqrt{2n}}$ and $a_{2n+1} = \dfrac5{\sqrt{2n+1}}$.  Then $\lim a_n = 0$, but you can't use Dirichlet to say that $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges.)

Comment: But  my function is monotonic, isn'T it?

Comment: Not until you've _proved_ it's monotonic. :-)

Comment: Well, if I didnt do any wrong calculation, I proved that it is.

Comment: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n \frac{1}{e} < 1$, correct?

Comment: Ahhh, of course - that's a much clearer way of doing it than using any asymptotic estimates, to be sure.  That just hadn't gotten mentioned in your question so I figured it was worth calling out explicitly.

Comment: In this case, the Dirichlet test applies! But what aboutthe uniform convergence at [-1/e, 1/e)? Should it be considered (analyzed)? I am really confused about where should I test it (clearly, not out of [-1/e,1/e])

Comment: That, sadly, I can't really help you with - issues of uniformity are not my strong point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence radius $r$ of $\sum a_nx^n$ is given by:
$$
r^{-1}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}
$$
By [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation):
$$
e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^n}{e\sqrt{ n}}\right)^{1/n}\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)^{1/n}=e
$$
Therefore $r=1/e$. The series converges absolutely for $|x|<1/e$ and converges uniformly on compact subset of $]-1/e,1/e[$. Since the series converges, as the PO said, for $-1/e$, it also converges uniformly on any compact subset of $[-1/e,1/e[$ (just pick the larger $N$ of the two as in $n>N\Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon, \forall x\in]-1/e,1/e[$ and in $x=-1/e$).

The series is not uniformly convergent on $[-1/e,1/e[$, for otherwise $|\sum_{k=n}^mf_k(x)|\leq\varepsilon$ for $f_k(x)= \frac{k^k}{k!}x^k,\forall n,m>N, \forall x\in [-1/e,1/e[$ (uniformly cauchy=uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$); as $x\to 1/e$, since $f_k(x)$ are all continuous, $|\sum_{k=n}^mf_k(1/e)|\leq\varepsilon$. We arrive at the conclusion that the series converges for $x=1/e$, which is a contradiction.

In my intuitive understanding, since the series blows up at $x=1/e$, it cannot have a uniform convergence as $x$ approaches $1/e$.

Comment: Ok, but if the series converges for $x=-\frac{1}{e}$, why the series doesn not converges uniformly on the interval $[-1/e, 1/e[$?

Comment: @Giiovanna You are right, it should be uniform on a compact subset of $[-1/e,1/e[$.

Comment: I dont see why your proof for the not uniformly convergence at [-1/e, 1/e) does not implies that the series also does not converges uniformly on (-1/e, 1/e)

Comment: @Giiovanna Whatever you mean (I don't get you at the moment, you said it true, but I am addressing your original question, and your comment is not making sense to me), its not going to happen for the $\dots,1/e[$ part. The biggest subset you can have uniform convergence is $[-1/e,1/e-\varepsilon]$ for arbitrary small $\varepsilon>0$, but no matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ is, it is not the same as $[-1/e,1/e[$.